# A production quality OpenSocial .NET library?

Tags: .net, opensocial, apache-shindig

I'm looking for production quality OpenSocial/Shindig .NET library, both Container and Client.

I only found [Baadal](http://sites.google.com/site/baadalsharp/) (and a [dead project on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenSocial)). What are you guys using?

Answer (score 3):

As client library, you can use http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-net-client/

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://code.google.com/p/pesta/ and http://www.codeplex.com/raya.

Comment: Not quite what I meant by production quality (haven't looked at the code, but I don't see heavy user activity). Thanks for the reference though.

Answer (score 1):

Myspace just open sourced their OpenSocial gadget parser and renderer and will be adding a full opensocial container implementation.

http://code.google.com/p/negroni/

Answer (score 1):

Several months ago I started working on implementation of opensocial specification on .NET. I think it will be useful to implement opensocial container on .NET which can be easily integrated in existing ASP.NET (MVC) site via nuget package. Right now it's far from being finished, but I have some results which you can check here if interested:

- [catpic.codeplex.com](http://catpic.codeplex.com) - project site
- *Install-Package Catpic* - nuget
  package  - just create new ASP.NET MVC 3 site and try to install it
- [catpic.apphb.com](http://catpic.apphb.com) - CI build with demo site